# How can I use regular expression as selector in angular animation?

Tags: regex, angularjs, animation

Is it possible to write something like this?

```
myModule.animation(/.*-animate/, function () { ... })
```

Comment: Sorry you can't. Only CSS selectors are allowed.

Comment: In CSS I can use `[class*="-animate"]` instead of regex. As I understand from your comment and error `Expecting class selector starting with '.'` there is no alternative in angular?

Comment: Not sure if I an answer this, but ngAnimation is using jqLite to find elements. So the behavior of the selector depends on what you have installed. If you have jQuery, then you can use selectors that work with that otherwise you are limited to what jqLite can do. I'm not sure if jQuery supports `*=` selectors or what version of jQuery.